# Internal : Collection fields are defined but cannot be matched to the incoming collection - in blueprism

Tags: collections, blueprism

I want collect Financial historical data from NASDAQ link https://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/ge/historical. In this I am spying date element and using "get table" I can get whole table data for date, open, high,... which I am putting in collection but the thing is I am not able to give column name to collection. I made 6 field for each all 6 column you can see in image attched. But when i run the programv I get an error "Internal : Collection fields are defined but cannot be matched to the incoming collection - The collection definition does not contain the field Column1".  if I dont add field I get data in collection which has default column name column 1, column 2, ...column 6 . But I want to have their specific column name. I think the problem is with the data type I am using while creating field in collection. I tried different combination for the data type but still...Please help me on that. enter image description here[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQibI.png)[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDUjl.png)
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neMhs.png)[image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4E70.png)

Answer (score 3):

The error is exactly as it says; the fields cannot be matched; in other words, the fields should match. Since you get default field names from the Read stage, then you should either rename the fields before passing the collection to the process or have the collection receiving the collection at the process level have no fields defined (it will get the headers defined from the object and you can rename the fields after that, or just use the default column names, but that's not practical).

To rename the fields, you can use the default object "Utility - Collection Manipulation", either actions "Rename Collection Fields" or "Rename Field".

- Rename Collection Fields
  You will have to supply the collection containing the read table (Main Collection) and a collection containing the same headers as the collection containing the read table (New Headers), and in the first row, the new headers (it was designed like that, it's not that intuitive; it took me a good while to figure it out). The collection New Headers should look like the below:

  [image]
- Rename Field
  For this one, you will need to loop over each header. `Collection In` will be the collection containing the read table, and you insert each header to change one at a time. (e.g. first loop iteration will have `Column1` as Field Name and `date` as New Name, second loop iteration will have `Column2` and `open`, etc)

Comment: first I want to create collection and add 6 field(date, open...) while creating. Then I want to read values from NASDAQ and then store in the created collection.  your answer is renaming the field which makes adding more steps in process. So I want to give field name while creating collection.Is their any way to do the?

Comment: @PriyaSangle No you cannot predefine the field names when reading the table.